# Given String with space between words. Taking each Word in an Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexing

As I wrote in the title, there is a given String with space between words. I need to substring each word as an arrays' one element. I wrote something. But, It does not work as It is supposed to.

```
String line =  ("<ID1> <ID2> d1|<ID3> <ID2> d2|<ID4> <ID5> d3|");

    int CountChar = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i++){
        if( line.charAt(i) == '|'){
                CountChar++;
        }
    }

    int[] MatrixIndex = new int[CountChar];
    for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<MatrixIndex.length; j++){
        if( line.charAt(i) == '|'){
            CountChar++;
            System.out.println(i);
            MatrixIndex[j] = i;
        }}
    }
```

Comment: tag it with progamming language tag as well, so that others with that skill can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String[] words = line.split(" ");
```